# What operators preserve antisymmetry?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, openfermion

I would like to understand better what kind of operators maintain antisymmetry as explained in [Quantum simulation of chemistry with sublinear scaling in basis size](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-019-0199-y):

> Evolution under the Hamiltonian will maintain antisymmetry provided that it exists in the initial state (a consequence of fermionic Hamiltonians commuting with the electron permutation operator).

I have further assumed that the electron permutation operator is given by [Low-Depth Quantum Simulation of Materials](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.8.011044)
\begin{equation}
f_{swap} = 1 + a_p^\dagger a_q + a_q^\dagger a_p - a_p^\dagger a_p - a_q^\dagger a_q.
\end{equation}
I am, for the moment, only interested in one-body electronic Hamiltonians, such as the kinetic or external potential terms. This one-body Hamiltonians have the form
\begin{equation}
H = h_{pq} a_p^\dagger a_q + \text{Hermitian conjugate}
\end{equation}
However, if I try to perform the commutator of $f_{swap}$ and $H$ above using OpenFermion, it does not return 0: [Collab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CKl-9tCID3dMKCz9KrB5I-bwfcZMqK9c?usp=sharing).
I have also tried with Givens rotations $e^{\theta(a_p^\dagger a_q- a_q^\dagger a_p)}$ and it does not seem to work either.

**Is the problem that $f_{swap}$ is not the electronic permutation operator? Or what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is $h_{pq}$ real?

Comment: If so, then $H$ and $f$ should certainly commute!

Comment: Thanks @JahanClaes. Yes, I had taken $h_{pq}$ real. But if I try to commute them (see the collab above) it doesn't seem to. That's why I am surprised.